# Counting from monday to friday consecutively bigquery sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to find a result with two conditions in google bigquery.

1. Employees who worked from Monday through Friday consecutively will get an additional pay of 8 hour amount of wage.
2. Condition above is valid for workers who worked more than 15 hours (15 hrs <) per week.

| id | date | hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | 2020-01-05 | 12 |
| abc123 | 2020-01-06 | 5 |
| abc123 | 2020-01-07 | 14 |
| abc123 | 2020-01-08 | 7 |
| abc123 | 2020-01-09 | 6 |
| abc123 | 2020-01-10 | 12 |

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have one row per employee per day, then you can handle this by using window functions.  The focus will be on Mondays, but the idea is to count the hours and days for a given row and the four days following.

So, to get the Mondays where a given `id` matches the conditions and is eligible for a bonus:

```
select id, date
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by id
                            order by unix_date(date)
                            range between current row and 4 following
                           ) as day_count,
             sum(hours) over (partition by id
                              order by unix_date(date)
                              range between current row and 4 following
                             ) as hours_count
      from t
     ) t
where extract(dayofweek from date) = 2 and
      day_count = 5 and
      hours_count >= 15;
```

Comment: I sincerely apologize for not being explaining the full context. Your assumption is correct but what if there are many more rows? like from 2018 to 2021? I don't think the where condition would work in this context with such a large date range.

Comment: @hustlecorean . . . Of course it would.  This gets all Monday/id combinations that meet your condtiions.